# android Supporting Multiple Screens Calculation

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I recently had a doubt

I put 40px * 40 px images in drawable folder.

and put 40px * 40 px images in drawable [hdpi] again .

Then Tabhost set this picture

[hdpi] exists and does not exist

Size two pictures displayed on the screen is not the same and why?

They are all the same 40px * 40px

why?

Different folder will result in a different calculation methods it?

PS:[My phone will pre-select [hdpi] folder]

Answer (score 0):

- If running on mdpi device 150x150 px image will take up 150*150 dp of screen space.
- If running on hdpi device 150x150 px image will take up 100*100 dp of screen space.
- If running on xhdpi device 150x150 px image will take up 75*75 dp of screen space.

The other way around: say, you want to add an image to your application and you need it to fill 100*100 dp control, you'll need to create different size images for supported screen sizes:

```
100*100 px image for mdpi
150*150 px image for hdpi
200*200 px image for xhdpi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create drawable folder in res folder and add all images in drawable folder.
 Actually in android there are different resolutions screens and every resolution have fix limitation    for retrieving the images on specific folders like - hdpi, ldpi ,mdpi etc. When we create drawable folder in res then if any different resolution screens will occurred then it will pic the image from drawable folder.

Comment: So all lost in the default folder is not recommended practice?